# Replacing text with gsub R

Tags: r, regex

I want to replace parts of a text Supposedly `gsub` would be capabale to do it.

This is an example of the kind of text:

```
text <- "[2017-12-29 18:24:52] Comentario añadido: SOME RANDOM TEXT I NEED ANALYZE 
[2017-12-29 18:24:52] Comentario añadido: OTHER RANDOM TEXT
[2017-12-29 19:24:52] Comentario añadido: BLA BLA BLA
[2017-12-29 20:24:52] Comentario añadido: BLA BLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLA
[2017-12-29 21:24:52] Comentario añadido: BLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLA
[2017-12-29 22:24:52] Comentario añadido: BLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLA"
```

this is the desired result:

```
"   | SOME RANDOM TEXT I NEED ANALYZE 
    | OTHER RANDOM TEXT
    | BLA BLA BLA
    | BLA BLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLA
    | BLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLA
    | BLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLA"
```

the idea is replace that info in order to savbe space and perform another analyzsys with less text.

This is what i get with `gsub`:

```
gsub("\\[.*\\] Comentario añadido:", " ° ", text)
[1] " °  BLA BLA BLABLA BLA BLA"
```

How can i achieve to replace al the cases?

thx in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may  make `.` not match newlines:

```
gsub("(?n)\\[.*?] Comentario añadido:", " ° ", text)
      ^^^^
```

I also advise to use a lazy dot, `.*?`, just in case there are more `]` chars on the line later. See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/YI7Q2Y).

Another solution may be

```
gsub("\\[[^][]*] Comentario añadido:", " ° ", text)
```

Here, `[^][]*` matches zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`.